# Force Webpack to build output from invalid TypeScript code

Tags: typescript, webpack

Basically, it's not good to make Webpack bundle the source code, when errors exist. However, I often need to check `console.log()` output when **radically** rewriting my TypeScript code. I'll show the simplified example.

Suppose, in the below code I decide to replace type of `parameter` from `CertainType1` to `CertainType2`:

```js
testFunction(parameter: CertainType1): CertainTypeFoo {

    const a: CertainTypeA = doSomethingWithCertainType1Or2(parameter);
    // check "a" value here!
    console.log(a);

    // I don't care what occurs here YET
    const b: CertainTypeB = doSomethingElseWithCertainType1(parameter);
    const foo: CertainTypeFoo = getInstanceOfFoo(a, b);

    // do something with foo...

    return foo;
}
```

When I replace `testFunction(parameter: CertainType1): CertainTypeFoo` with `testFunction(parameter: CertainType2): CertainTypeFoo`, function becomes invalid because `doSomethingElseWithCertainType1` requires `CertainType1` only.

But I don't care about it YET: **for now**, I need to check `const a` value, and when I make sure that everything O'K with `const a`, I'll advance and deal with `const b`.

Improper solutions:

1. **Comment out everything from `const b` row**: `testFunction` must return `CertainTypeFoo`. Assume that it is not simple to get mock instance by other way.
2. **First rewrite all code to valid TypeScript, than begin checking `const a`**:  "rewrite all code" could take some hours for real applications.

Comment: TypeScript does what you want by default. See that the `--noEmitOnError` flag is false by default, per the docs at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html . Something in your setup is disabling this behavior, so you'll need to provide a minimal, complete example of your config if you want help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

@GeorgeP in his comment was right about TypeScript part, but it also required to setup

```
module.exports = {

  // ... 

  optimization: {
    noEmitOnErrors: false
  }
}
```

for Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Simply cast the type to what you want:

```
testFunction(parameter: CertainType2): CertainTypeFoo {

    const a: CertainTypeA = doSomethingWithCertainType1Or2(parameter);
    // check "a" value here!
    console.log(a);

    // I don't care what occurs here YET
    const b: CertainTypeB = doSomethingElseWithCertainType1(parameter as CertainType1);
    const foo: CertainTypeFoo = getInstanceOfFoo(a, b);

    // do something with foo...

    return foo;
}
```

By doing explicit casting, you are telling typescript that you don't care what it thinks (or does not think) this type is, and typescript will respect that.

There is no need to change the compiler flags